# In machine learning projects what are some bottlenecks of working with two OS?

Tags: python, machine-learning, mlops

Previously I've developed using windows OS then in production used Linux. While doing that there were lots of OS differences that gave me a hard time such as different OS installing different dependencies, etc...

I want to know if there are any other problems (references are welcome)? or maybe a way to work with two different OS seemlessly?

Comment: It depends on various factors on what you are actually stuck on - i.e. dealing with path separators (through `pathlib` or `os.path`), GUIs, usage/linkage/import of external non-Python libraries are just some of the individual topics you will need to deal with, and thus this question cannot simply be answered in a general way when there are more than three questions raised already.  That said, once you know your scope and did the proper mitigation for cross-platform differences, the "hard time" becomes less hard and is a matter of following the best-practice specific to the topic at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Developing and deploying to difference cause many problem as you have experienced.
I have two suggestion for you:

- Developing using remote server - VS Code, PyCharm support it pretty well, and currently I'm using this approach
- Developing locally with vscode + WSL/Docker

Comment: Yes, we were using the first method however we cannot anymore...

Comment: So you can try method two, vscode support WSL pretty well